# Is cursor() a class inside the connect() class in sqlite3 module in python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I recently started learning sqlite3 in python and found the `cursor()` to be confusing.

```
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect('datebase.db')
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute('')
```

Is `cursor()` a nested class inside `connect()` or is it a classmethod or neither. 
Please explain.

Comment: The code is open source ;)

Comment: @Rightleg: this particular module is also written in C, using the Python C API, so may be a little more complex to grok.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse methods with classes or instances. Just because a method returns an instance, doesn't mean that that class lives inside another class.

A method runs some code, that code can create instances of *any class they like*. The SQLite library does this, *roughly* (the [exact code is more complex, and written in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Modules/_sqlite/connection.c#L285-L323)):

```
class Connection:
    def cursor(self):
        cursor = Cursor(self)
        if self.row_factory is not None:
            cursor.row_factory = self.row_factory
        return cursor

class Cursor:
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection
        # set other attributes for the instance
```

So the `Connection().cursor()` method returns an object that holds a reference back to the connection, but the class itself is defined elsewhere.

The module gives you access to those classes directly; you can create the cursor just the same way:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.Connection
<class 'sqlite3.Connection'>
>>> sqlite3.Cursor
<class 'sqlite3.Cursor'>
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> conn
<sqlite3.Connection object at 0x105938570>
>>> sqlite3.Cursor(conn)
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x105bcbea0>
```

However, using the `Connection().cursor()` method ensures you won't forget to properly attach it to the right connection, and the `Connection.cursor()` method also does some internal clean-up that's important for memory management (I omitted it above, but you can study the C code I linked).

Note that Python does not have a privacy model like C# or Java have. In those languages you can use a nested, inner class to provide privilege access to attributes that other code is not allowed to use. In Python, nested classes are *just attributes on the parent class*, nothing more. There usually is very little use for such nesting, and only makes things less readable.

Answer (score 0):

As Carles Explained, `.cursor()` is the method here that returns the object of type `Cursor` which is a class. To verify this for yourself, open a temporary connection using the python interpreter:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connection(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()
```

Now, After getting the cursor, just type:

```
type(c)
```

And you will get:

```
<class 'sqlite3.Cursor'>
```

Comment: This says nothing about where the cursor class is defined however. It could still be a nested class.

Comment: In this case, for example, the class is defined in C code, and the name is set [by a C type definition](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Modules/_sqlite/cursor.c#L972). The developers could have used `sqlite.cursor.Cursor` too, or `sqlite.connection.Connection.Cursor`, and made it available at any of those names.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not familiar with C language, but as a user of CPython (and especially the `sqlite3` module), you don't really need to care at what hierarchy level, a particular class is defined. The OP's confusion was regarding the `cursor()` method, not the `Cursor` class (note the capitalization).

Comment: From the question: *Is cursor() a nested class inside connect() or is it a classmethod or neither*. Your answer doesn't address any of that.

Comment: Yup, and from my answer: *.cursor() is the method here that returns the object of type Cursor* (which I hope succinctly explains?).

Comment: Not really, because it doesn't tell you if that class is nested, or anything else about the relationship between method and class.